# Append html code with var word from anther element

Tags: jquery

I would like to append this html code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/+++++?published"></script>
```

to this div content

```
<div class="content"><h>Arts</h></div>
```

and replace +++++ with the text between `<h></h>`

finally the result would be

```
<div class="content"><h>Arts</h><script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/Arts?published"></script></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var headerText = $(".content").text();
var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/' + headerText + '?published"></scr' + 'ipt>';
var newText = '<div class="concent"><h>' + headerText + '</h>' + script + '</div>';

$(".content").replaceWith(newText);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b7cBF/2/

Comment: While posting my own answer I can't seem to get `</script>` tags to work within strings - the browser seems to ignore the string and just close the script tag instantly (chrome 32). I tried yours and same issue.

Comment: Same problem here. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Crazysheep ha. Javascript interpreter sees </script> and ends the script tag, and therefore outputs the rest as regular text.

Comment: Surprisingly simple and effective (although confusing to read at a later date perhaps) fix that I completely missed, nice. I'm also pretty surprised that manually appended scripts do get parsed and executed which is nice.

Comment: OP could provide comments for clarity, or put it inside a function with a fitting name :p

Answer (score 0):

Give it an id

```
<script id="myscript" type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/+++++?published"></script>
```

Then

```
var sauce = $('#myscript').attr('src');
$('#myscript').attr('src', sauce.replace("+++++", $('h').text()));
$('#myscript').appendTo($('div.content'));
```

Example with a `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/b7cBF/

Comment: I don't think the script should be in the html source - you'll get 404 errors when trying to fetch from some path with +++++. Should have the script in the js code as a string.